# Extract attributes from SDP record using Windows Bluetooth API

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I'm new to Windows Bluetooth development, and am using [BluetoothSdpEnumAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothsdpenumattributes) to parse sdp attributes in a callback function. Currently I face 2 difficulties:

- I don't know the what attribute each attributeID corresponds to.
- I don't know how to further parse data with type SDP_ST_SEQUENCE. Is it like an array? If so, how do I know the length of its elements, and what type the elements should be converted to?(This actually results from the first difficulty)

An example that extracts most important attribtues such as serviceID, serviceClassID in a callback funtion would be appreciated.

## Edit 1

Thanks for help from Mike, I have read about [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/), which starting from p1240 describes meaning of each SDPAttributeId. The next difficulty is somehow I did not find how Data Element Sequence is organized. For example, for a ServiceClassIdList, the bytes of sdp attribute are:

```
35 11 1c 02 03 03 02 1d 19 41 5f 86 f2 22 a2 10 6a 0a 77
```

I read from p1222 that the first 5 bits 0b00110=6 suggest it's a data element sequence, and the following 3 bits 0b101=5 indicate the size of sequence is stored in the next 2 bytes, which is 0x11=17.
From [here](http://magictale.com/1749/bluetooth-for-dummies-getting-data-from-sdp/), I learn that the 1st byte seems to be a field type descriptor. For example, 0x19 indicates the following is a 16-bit UUID; and in my case, 0x1c is a full 128-bit uuid. Yet I could not find a table of what structure each field type descriptor indicates.

```
// Code scheme for parsing SDP attributes.
//...
int result = BluetoothSdpEnumAttributes( pBlob->pBlobData, pBlob->cbSize, callback, 0 );
//...

BOOL __stdcall callback( ULONG uAttribId, LPBYTE pValueStream, ULONG cbStreamSize, LPVOID pvParam )
{
SDP_ELEMENT_DATA element;
    printf("Callback() uAttribId: %lu\n", uAttribId);
    if ( BluetoothSdpGetElementData( pValueStream, cbStreamSize, &element ) != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        // Just a verification
        printf("BluetoothSdpGetElementData() failed with error code %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        switch(uAttribId){
            case 0: // ServiceRecordHandle
                break;
            case 1: // ServiceClassIdList
                break;
            //...
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before working with Bluetooth it is always creat to read something about technology you use. The good start is there: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/ )SDP also described there).

Comment: Thanks for the document, which tells me the structure of sdp records. But somehow I didn't find contents about how data field in data element sequence(type=6) are organized, although I can find some patterns by observing the bytes.